# How set different listselector

Tags: android, android-layout

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                    int position, long id) {

        if(position == 0)
            mainListView.setSelector(R.drawable.settings_selector_up);
        else if(position == mainListView.getCount())
            mainListView.setSelector(R.drawable.settings_selector_down);
        else
            mainListView.setSelector(R.drawable.settings_selector_mid);
            }
                });
```

I have listview, my listview has a rounded corner. I use 3 selectors for listview. So when i select  in the first item of listView should work settings_selector_up which has a rounded corner only in topleft and topright. In the middle of listview no rounded corners, the last item of listview should have round  bottomleft and bottomright corner. I use this in onitemClickListener, but it is not a good point. Is there another a way to do this?

Comment: are you using adapter for setting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a pretty quick problem to solve but actual it is not. You should modify your adapter and make it to accept 3 different type of items (up, down, mid) and then change the getView in something like this:

```
...
if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);

   switch (type) {
       case TYPE_ITEM_UP:
           convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_up);
           break;

   case TYPE_ITEM_DOWN:
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_down);
        break;
       ...
    }
}
...
```

Take a look to this [example](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296), you can reduce your problem to that, very helpful. I used the same solution for the exact your problem and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any adapter then in getview method for returning view you can set selector