# listview border's selector

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]

In emulator 2 I have a rounded border listview (it's fine for me), but when I try scrolling, the listview, the border's corner changed (as seen in the emulator 1) I use list_selector for that. What should I do here for keeping border's rounded everytime when I try scroll the listview?

The code of this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411374/listviews-border-changed-in-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

just use the nine-patch (it's can scale in appropriate way) image for the background of the whole listView. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to read this post, I answered yesterday to the exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396253/how-set-different-listselector/8396428#8396428).

Essentially you should modify your adapter and make it to accept 3 different type of items (up, down, mid) and then change the getView.

Comment: Yes I did exactly what you said. I change the getview but when I scrolling it the rounded border's changed

Comment: here is the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411374/listviews-border-changed-in-scrolling