# ListView Activity in Android

Tags: android

How to differentiate between two items in the ListView Activity(Android)?? As i am creating my own contact list and want to differentiate items as online and offline users. That means i want to change the text color of different items.

this is my sample code, where i am inserting the contact one by one, what exactly i need to change here -
@Override

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    // ViewHolder will buffer the assess to the individual fields of the row layout.
    ViewHolder holder;

    // Recycle existing view if passed as parameter, This will save memory and time on Android
    // This only works if the base layout for all classes are the same.
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(items[position]);

    return rowView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have a custom adapter and then implementing your logic on the getView method. You can easily make the adapter accepting 2 different item types (online,offline) and then changing all what you want based on that, you could indeed have different layout.

I have already answered a similar question, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396253/how-set-different-listselector/8396428#8396428).

Comment: I have edited my question with sample code, can you please look in to that and help out, what exactly i need to change there . thnx in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can create two list for each type of user or you can set some parameter in each to check its online or offline

Comment: How it's possible to display two list at the same time??? I want to display all the items at the same time with different text color based on online/offline status.